# Boostrap classes not showing in browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap, I am trying out different things and when I add the classes to different elements some work, and others dont show up in dev tools. The class on the ul works, but on the li and 'a' doesnt.
`

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link-active" href="">About Us</a>
          </li>
```

`

I tried to restart the project and reconnect bootstrap but neither solution worked.

Comment: How are you importing the bootstrap CSS and JS? If the imports are normal, please show your full imports for your page as CSS is overridden with elements defined last/below

Comment: <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

Comment: <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      defer
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      defer
    ></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you put an extra `-` between `nav-link` and `active` class. The correct way is this one `<a class="nav-link active" href="#">About Us</a>`